# HTML site not showing certain elements when not using live server

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

When i use the live server in VS Code everything works as expected, however when I open the site via files it doesn't show certain elements. I've noticed that it's the ones that require linking to other files. For example @font-face and background-image: url()

I've tried restarting my PC thinking that it just didn't load or something but that wasn't the case. The files and paths are structured correctly since it works in live server mode so I doubt that that's the problem

Heres parts of code that are most likely problematic and screenshots of file vs. live server

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Raleway;
    src: url(/fonts/Raleway-Medium.ttf);
  }
main{
    background-image: url('/img/pozadina.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

[Live server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phmo7.png)
[HTML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYz9l.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "_however when I open the site via files_"? Do you mean via the `file://` protocol in your browser? If so, the the reason why is because Live Server and your browser interpret the absolute paths differently (the ones that start with `/`). Live Server interprets them as configured, or by default, relative to your VS Code workspace folder. The browser interprets them relative to the root of your filesystem / the specified drive.

Comment: @user, I understand what you mean in theory, but I'm not sure how to fix the problem. I believe that what you're saying is correct. I just don't understand if it's something I have to change in my files or in the code or something completely different.

Comment: Well, you haven't asked a question in your question post or told us what the problem is. What's the problem? What's your question?

Comment: This question can be answered by (is a duplicate of) [Why does my file load correctly through Live Server, but not through my browsers' support for the file:// protocol?](/q/75637309/11107541)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, instead of adding one dot i had to add two. Now it works for both, browser file protocol and live server.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Raleway;
  src: url(../fonts/Raleway-Medium.ttf);
}
main{
  background-image: url('../img/pozadina.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add dots (.) before folders in path

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Raleway;
  src: url(./fonts/Raleway-Medium.ttf);
}
main{
  background-image: url('./img/pozadina.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: Yes, switching to absolute paths might be _a_ solution, but the asker hasn't qualified whether that's acceptable to them or not. They haven't even said whether it's important to them for things to work on both Live Server and browser's `file://` protocol.

Comment: Yes, that is the plan, I intend for it to work in the browsers file:// protocol. I've tried the solution with adding dots before the folders in path but that didn't work. The problem is most likely something else.